# quadratic equation what am I doing wrong?

Tags: quadratics

solve
$$ \sqrt{5x+19} = \sqrt{x+7} + 2\sqrt{x-5} $$

$$ \sqrt{5x+19} = \sqrt{x+7} + 2\sqrt{x-5} \Rightarrow $$ 
$$ 5x+19 = (x+7) + 4\sqrt{x-5}\sqrt{x+7} + (x+5) \Rightarrow $$ 
$$ 3x + 17 = 4\sqrt{x-5}\sqrt{x+7} \Rightarrow $$
$$ 9x^2 + 102x + 289 = 16(x+7)(x-5) \Rightarrow $$
$$ 9x^2 + 102x + 289 = 16(x^2+ 2x - 35) \Rightarrow $$
$$ 7x^2 - 70x - 849 = 0 \Rightarrow $$
$$ b^2 - 4ac = (-70)^2 - 4 \cdot 7 \cdot (-849) = 28672=2^{12}\cdot7 $$

then I calculate the solution using the discriminant as
$$ 5 + 32\frac{\sqrt7}7 $$
and
$$ 5 - 32\frac{\sqrt7}7 $$

but when I plug in the values I find out that they are wrong,
does it have to do with the fact that I square the equation twice?
if so what is the best way to go about solving this equation?

Comment: Line 3 above has an error. You did the equivalent of expanding $(a+2b)^2$ as:$$(a+2b)^2=a^2+4ab+b^2$$while the correct expansion is:$$(a+2b)^2=a^2+4ab+4b^2$$Plus the error spotted below by @Crostul

Comment: There is a mistake in the very first step, when you pass to squares. The square of $2\sqrt{x-5}$ is $4(x-5)$, not $(x+5)$.

Comment: Apart from possible mistakes in your computations, bear in mind that you only prove implications ($\Rightarrow$), hence if $x$ is a solution of your equation, then it must be one of the values you find in the end. But that does not mean that all values are solutions. Or even that at least one is a solution, as your equation may also have no solution at all. You have to check afterwards.

Comment: oh thank you I have spent 1 hour on this dumb mistake:)

Comment: well as far as I know if the discriminant is greater than 0 then the equation will have two real solutions, is this wrong? As in no complex numbers will be involved

Comment: You original equation is not a quadratic equation. When you square, usually you introduce new "solutions". A trivial example: you square equation $x=1$, then it becomes $x^2=1$, which has solutions $+1$ and $-1$, one of which is of course not a solution of $x=1$. That's the kind of problem that may arise. When you only prove implication in one direction, you have to check implication in the other direction, otherwise it may simply be wrong.

Comment: By the way, a solution of your equation must be $>5$, otherwise there is a problem with the square root. Here, your second solution is $<5$, so it certainly isn't a solution of your equation.

Comment: On line 4, it's $3x+7$, not $3x+17$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: thanks Jean that makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot a factor $4$ and wrote $x+5$ instead of $x-5$ in the third line, which should be
$$
5x+19=x+7+4\sqrt{x+7}\,\sqrt{x-5}+4(x-5)
$$
giving
$$
4\sqrt{x+7}\,\sqrt{x-5}=32
$$
or
$$
\sqrt{x+7}\,\sqrt{x-5}=8
$$
that becomes, after squaring,
$$
x^2+2x-99=0
$$
The roots of this are $-11$ and $9$, but only the latter is a solution of the original equation, because the existence conditions on the radicals give
\begin{cases}
5x+19\ge0\\[3px]
x+7\ge0\\[3px]
x-5\ge0
\end{cases}
that is, $x\ge5$.

Comment: why u expect all the numbers must be positive>????@egreg

Comment: @gloom Otherwise the square roots don't exist in the real numbers. Note that the equation is meaningless in the complex numbers, because the square root is not uniquely defined, unless one discusses about branches.

Comment: oh..you are right..i will make correction in my post...

Comment: but... $\sqrt{-1}$ is uniquely defined know???@egreg

Comment: @gloom Of course not: which one do you choose between $i$ and $-i$?

Comment: @gloom $i^2=(-i)^2=-1$ so no.

Comment: $i$ only know..@egreg

Comment: @gloom There is no function $f$ on the complex numbers such that $f(z)^2=z$ for every $z$ *and* $f(z_1z_2)=f(z_1)f(z_2)$ for all $z_1,z_2$. Note that the latter property is essential for the computation of roots of the original equation.

Comment: is it not a convention??

Comment: @gloom Writing $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is a bad, but sadly widespread abuse of notation. Carelessly manipulating $\sqrt{x}$ for $x<0$ is not only bad, it's wrong, as explained in previous comments.

Comment: thanks egreg for your reply, that does illuminate many things, in any case the complex numbers do not even constitute a field

Comment: @Gravity Your method was sound, weren't for the mistake in writing $x+5$ instead of $4(x-5)$. Usually I advice working out the existence conditions, so one has not to check the discovered roots back in the original equation.

Comment: @Gravity "in any case the complex numbers do not even constitute a field". Ahem... Yes, it's a field. But that does only guarantee properties of addition and multiplication, not roots. $\Bbb Q$ is also a field, but as you probably know, $\sqrt{2}$ does not exist in $\Bbb Q$. The real problem with square roots of complex numbers is there are two of them. Thus it's not a function. However, $\sqrt{x}$ is correctly defined as a function, on $\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: sorry I meant to say, it is not an ordered field because x^2 >= 0 must be the case for ordered fields, so the difference between C, Q, and R is that, Q and R are ordered fields, but C is not, that is what I meant to say. But yeah you probably know that already:=), just correcting my mistake. AGAIN!

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\sqrt{5x+19}&=\sqrt{x+7}+2\sqrt{x-5}\\
5x+19&=x+7+4(x-5)+4\sqrt{(x+7)(x-5)}\\
32&=4\sqrt{(x+7)(x-5)}\\
8&=\sqrt{(x+7)(x-5)}\\
64&=x^2+2x-35\\
0&=x^2+2x-99
\end{align}

which gives $x=9$ and $x=-11$ are the solutions.

But both are giving something like this..

$x=9\implies \sqrt {5(9)+19}=\sqrt{9+7}+2\sqrt{9-5}$
$\implies\sqrt{64}=\sqrt{16}+2\sqrt{4}\implies 8=8$ correct know...!!!!

$x=-11\implies\sqrt {5(-11)+19}=\sqrt{-11+7}+2\sqrt{-11-5}$
$\implies\sqrt{-36}=\sqrt{-4}+2\sqrt{-16}\implies 6i=2i+4i$

But by the series of comments given by the well wishers.. i could understand $x=-11$ is not possible...

Comment: I would not call x = -11 a solution.